# print floating point number assembler 8086

Tags: assembly, printing, numbers, floating-point

I'm trying to print a floating point number using assembler 8086 and tasm!!! But i don't have any idea about how to do this.
I have the number in a variable like this:

> var dd 3.14235565212

Can you help me? Of curse the number is in the floating point format(you know IEEE 754 or something like that)
thanks

Comment: Assuming it *is* IEEE 754, you can find detailed specifications here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008.  There's also some guidance in *The Art of assembly Language:* http://books.google.com/books?id=094tYob7ipQC&pg=PA95&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: You should use 3.1415926536 for a float near pi instead.

Comment: @drhirsch: I disagree. In assembly language on an x86, you should normally just use `fldpi`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a floating point unit available (pretty much a given, anymore), the easy way is to convert it to BCD format using FBSTP, then use the CPU to convert individual digits to ASCII/ISO/Unicode/whatever.